# How to move text in a input field?

Tags: css, svg, input

So I'm in the process of learning and trying to make my own website. I have most of the form how I would like it but, I'm not sure how to clear the placeholder text away from the svg img so it will be legible. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

[Screen Capture of my problem. Also if you would tell me if it looks okay that would be great also!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxsKH.jpg)

```
.inputTagz{
    padding-left: 25px;
    cursor: text;
    font-size: 14px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: px;
    padding-top: 11px;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
    margin-top:20px;
    font-weight:700;
}

#name{
    background-image: url("man.svg");
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    background-position: 11px 8px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#emailPhone{
    background-image: url("mail.svg");
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    background-position: 11px 8px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#password{
    background-image: url("lock.svg");
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    background-position: 11px 8px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#formDiv{
    width: 450px;
    float: left;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: you want that text readable, right ? after your image is the text?

Comment: What is the width of input field?

Comment: Yes sir, when I try to use padding that results in the input box stretching instead of affecting the placeholder text.

Comment: where did you put your svg? into your placeholder?

Comment: I put them in as background imgs of the different inputs thinking that it would be fairly simple to move the placeholder text to the right some...Guess I may have been wrong lol.

Comment: check my post code. it will help you. see below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to edit your place holder, you can use this

```
#emastrong textilPhone {
    background-image: url("mail.svg");
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    background-position: 11px 8px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#password {
    background-image: url("lock.svg");
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    background-position: 11px 8px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#emailPhone::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   padding-left: 25px;
}

#emailPhone::-moz-placeholder {
    padding-left: 25px;
}
#emailPhone:-moz-placeholder {   /* Older versions of Firefox */
    padding-left: 25px;
}
#emailPhone:-ms-input-placeholder { 
    padding-left: 25px;
}

#password::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   padding-left: 25px;
}

#password::-moz-placeholder {
    padding-left: 25px;
}
#password:-moz-placeholder {   /* Older versions of Firefox */
    padding-left: 25px;
}
#password:-ms-input-placeholder { 
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

please check the latest update about how to edit the placeholder. Thank you, I hope it will help you.

try this code...

Comment: Haha as soon as you made your answer I figured it out it's CSS3 tags. Thanks John.

Answer (score 3):

try this

**CSS**

```
input[type=text] {
      padding-left: 25px; //change it base on your desired output
}
```

see my sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dyceLgb5/)

Answer (score 3):

Hey guys thanks for answering my question I greatly appreciate it. The style I was looking for was the input-placeholder CSS3 tag.

I just added these sets of tags to my page. Hopefully I can help someone like me.

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    padding-left:20px; 
}
input::-moz-placeholder {
    padding-left:20px; 
}
input:-moz-placeholder {   /* Older versions of Firefox */
    padding-left:20px; 
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder { 
    padding-left:20px; 
}
```

[image: This is the results with the tag add.]

Answer (score 1):

Please add this css

```
input[type='text'] {
      padding-left: 25px;
      max-width : calc(100% - 25px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, you just need to remove the 'placeholder'attribute from the code for all three inputs in the form you created.

For your reference click [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it inside a parent div with separate **img** and **input** tag as follows:

```
<div id="some_id">
  <img src="http://images.brighthub.com/a3/d/a3d2a3f5888d96ddde78d526bf9448dddf2fb4aa_small.jpg">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name" id="some_text_id">
</div>
```

**EXAMPLE [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kx9kj190/)**